# What is the maximum resolution for using two external monitors with a Macbook Pro 15" Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I've got a MacBook Pro 15" retina with the NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB. I'm looking for two high-resolution monitors to hook up to it. Can anyone tell me what the maximum resolution is that is supported for both monitors in this setup? Specifically, can it support two 3840x2160 monitors? I've got the MacBook screen itself set to 2880 X 1800.

Answer (score 1):

It can support 2 external screens over Thunderbolt at 2560x1600 or one 2560x1600 on Thunderbolt & one at 1920x1200 via HDMI (There is a linked report of getting all 3 working, but with overheating issues.)

Everymac is a good source of info for this sort of thing.
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.7-15-mid-2012-retina-display-specs.html